# gulp uncss unexpectedly removing some "ignored" classes

Tags: javascript, regex, uncss, gulp-uncss

I'm using gulp uncss.  This is my task code:

```
gulp.task('uncss', () => {
  return gulp.src($uncss.src)
    .pipe(uncss({
        html: JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync('./sitemap.json', 'utf-8')),
        ignore: [/\.no-\w+/g, /\.is-\w+/g, /\.plyr\w+/g, /\.lazy\w+/g, /\.\w+\s?\.is-\w+/g]
    }))
    // .pipe(cssnano())
    .on('error', handleErrors)
    .pipe(gulp.dest($uncss.dest))
});
```

The following line

```
.is-menu-open .menu__btn span:before, .is-menu-open .menu__btn span:after {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

is compiled as, once I've run the code through the gulp task above.

```
.is-menu-open .menu__btn span:before {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Any thoughts, my regex skills are some what lacking!

Essentially I need to ignore any classes with `.is-` anywhere in the selector.

Comment: I have a feeling `uncss` isn't catching the global flag of the regexs, as `/\.is-\w+/g` should catch that. Does specifying the whole class `.is-menu-open` work? Also, would inline ignoring (on the css) work for you? like so: `/* uncss:ignore */`

Comment: I was testing the expressions on https://regex101.com/ and they were matching as expected.  I did not know about `/* uncss:ignore */` , i'll give that a whirl.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://github.com/giakki/uncss#within-nodejs):

> Regular expressions for the ignore and ignoreSheets options should be wrapped in quotation marks.
>
> `{"ignore": [
>           ".unused",
>           "/^#js/"
>   ]}`

Comment: Example you provided is only if using `uncssrc` option to load options from json file. This is not the case if using `ignore` option.